# Alert is not showing during manual but alert is showing in automation

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, alert

I need to clear the textbox and enter value .After that i am moving to next step.This scenario is working fine in manual but not in automation.After enter the value and trying to move next step but alert is showing with following message
"Textbox field should not be empty".But already value is in textbox which i entered.Anyone please give me suggestion.

Comment: After entering a text in the text box, your application is not treating[I believe it is bug of you application] that you already entered text. So better before moving to next step click next to the text box and perform move to next step scenario.

Comment: Heyi thanks i clicked the same textbox again after entered the value now alert is not showing.

Comment: You should delete this question since it won't be useful for future readers since it was a bug in your script.

Answer (score 0):

After enter the value in the textbox just click the same textbox then alert will not show in this type of scenario